# CentOS 6 phpMyAdmin access denied

Tags: centos6

I am having issues setting up my VPS with phpMyAdmin.

My error message:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin/ on this server.
```

My phpMyAdmin config:

```
    # phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
#
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
  </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.01
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

I had 127.0.0.1 to my public IP and that still didn't work,

Also the tut I followed: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-a-centos-6-4-vps

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not and will never be your public ip. Please consider professional help, before exposing machines to the public internet without proper knowledge!

Comment: Please refrain from hosting without reading, 127 is localhost aka a  loopback address. I and I quote say "I had 127.0.0.1 to my public", but it so my public ip wasn't displayed.

Comment: Ok, this was quite misunderstandable. Usually adjusting localhost to the desired IP's/Subnets should do the job. Did you restart Apache after adjusting? What is displayed in access/error.log as accessing IP?

Comment: All it said and says when I restart is that the FQDN cannot be found on localhost.

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

```
Require ip 127.0.0.1
```

is wrong in your context. By restricting access to the phpMyAdmin directory only to localhost, only a local client (say from the command line or a firefox run on the local display) will be granted access to this directory. If you are running this server on a VPS, chances are you want to be less restrictive, for instance granting access to your home ip address (most likely the NAT router) or the place where you're accessing your VPS from.

What most people will do is secure their phpmyadmin access by allowing it only through an ssl protected link (see https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts for instance), then have a less stringent restriction for the directory, such as:

```
Require group admin
```

or even drop altogether Apache authentication with a

```
Require all granted
```

as phpMyAdmin will take over with its own, mysql-based authentication.

The phpMyAdmin config portion will look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
     <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        SSLEngine on
       #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed. Note that you'd better do with creating your own 
       # private certificates (see any openssl tutorial) and point at them here
       SSLCertificateFile   /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

     # additional trick: many robots try to access paths variants to myurl/phpmyadmin
     # a minor trick is to choose an entirely different alias to avoir their clogging your logs 
     # with many break in attempts.

        Alias /mysqladmin /my/path/to/phpmyadmin
        <Directory "/my/path/to/phpmyadmin">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
```